# Did Star Trek: Lower Decks just make a reference to Breaking Bad?

Tags: breaking-bad, reference, star-trek-lower-decks

In [Star Trek: Lower Decks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Lower_Decks) S3E9 "Trusted Sources", there are repeated and frequent references to a pie eating contest about to be held. Mariner is covered in blueberry pie filling and keeps talking about preparing for the contest. This seemed to me to be a direct reference to a scene in Breaking Bad where Badger explains to Skinny Pete about his own idea for a Star Trek: The Next Generation episode.

Was the pie eating contest a reference to the Breaking Bad scene?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes.

> *“That was inspired by the story of the pie-eating contest from Stand
> By Me,”* he says. *“Which Jerry O’Connell and Wil Wheaton, were both in.
> **Also, it was partly from Breaking Bad when one of the characters
> pitches his Star Trek episode – and it’s about a pie-eating contest.”***
>
> <sub><sup>[Inside the Star Trek: Lower Decks Season 3 Finale Easter Eggs - Star Trek: Lower Decks showrunner Mike McMahan takes us inside what it takes to make all of those deep Trek lore references a reality, and explains the ones you might have missed.](https://www.denofgeek.com/tv/inside-star-trek-lower-decks-season-3-finale-easter-eggs/)</sup></sub>